# Проверка input на дату

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь сделать проверку двух полей, в первом поле дата не должна быть меньше 01.1960 а во втором поле не больше чем текущая дата, и если даты не правильные то нужна какая-то подсказка возле поля, а не как я пытаюсь сделать в `alert` помогите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать? Я понимаю что я сравниваю со строкой, но вот как туда именно дату указать, я не знаю.

Код:

```js
  function validate_form( )
                    {
                        valid = true;

                        if (document.formValid.inputDateFirst.value < "01.01.1960")
                        {
                            alert("Дата не меньше чем 01.1960");
                            valid = false;
                        }

                        return valid;
                    }
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid" style="position: relative">
            <h4>Оберіть діапазон дат</h4>
            <form name ="formValid" class="form-inline" action="Xls" onsubmit="return validate_form( );">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Початкова дата</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputDateFirst"  class="inputDate form-control" id="inputDateFirst">
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Кінцева дата</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputDateSecond"  class="inputDate form-control" id="inputDateSecond" >
                </div>
                <button  class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" 
                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="xls">
                   Жми</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: как можно сравнивать даты в формате строки? как? 01.01.1960 ?

Comment: я дописал, я понимаю что делаю не так, и ищу подсказки как сравнить именно даты

Comment: В первую очередь вы должны конвертировать строку в mktime (strtotime) и только после сравнивать две даты. Какое значение у вас в document.formValid.inputDateFirst.value ?

Comment: я выбираю на форме datepicker-ом, например вот 24.11.2017

Comment: т.е ваша задача чтобы пользователь не смог выбрать дату меньне 1960 гда ?

Comment: да, в первом поле не меньше 1960 года, во втором не больше текущей даты, и желательно какое-то сообщение вывести в самом поле в виде подсказки, а не alert-ом как это делаю я

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю изначально вы некорректно задали свой вопрос, если вы используете `datapicker` нет необходимости самому проверять какую дату выбрал пользователь, это может сделать сам `datapicker`. Вот примерный код работы двух инпутов для выбора промежутка даты:

```
 function getCalendar(input1, input2) {
    var dateToday = new Date();


    $('#' + input1).datepicker({

        showOn: "button",
        autoSize: true,
        showAnim: "slide",
        dateFormat: "mm.dd.yy",
        buttonImage: "/icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: new Date(01, 01, 1960),
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#' + input2).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }

    });


    $('#' + input2).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        autoSize: true,
        showAnim: "slide",
        dateFormat: "mm.dd.yy",
        buttonImage: "/icon.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        maxDate: dateToday,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $('#' + input1).datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }

    });


 }
```

Вызываете функкцию, передаёте ID ваших инпутов, и всё. Можно просто использовать параметр `minDate` и установить нужную дату. В моём примере так же происходит проверка как первого инпута, так и второго(в зависемости друг от друга)

Comment: спасибо, проверю, потом отпишусь

Comment: а функцию вызвать так? а то у меня есть предчувствие что я что-то не так делаю( `<form name ="formValid" class="form-inline" action="Xls" onsubmit="getCalendar(inputDateFirst, inputDateSecond)">`

Comment: нет конечно, метод должен работать до отправки, в своём js файле просто вызовите getCalendar('inputDateFirst', 'inputDateSecond');

Answer (score 1):

Если не пугает HTML5 + проверка JS

```html
<form>
    <input type="date" name="myDate" min="1960-01-01">
    <input type="date" name="myDate" max="2018-11-27">
    <br/><input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: не все версии браузеров поддерживают type="date"

Comment: @Sorpok, ну потому и комментарий "Если не пугает HTML5"

Comment: получается что пугает)

Comment: @Sorpok на некоторых проектах/для некоторых задач он и меня пугает. Тут приходится делать выбор. Но для многих вещей он простой, прозрачный, клевый и надо его знать. Надеюсь поддержка браузеров вопрос времени. Предполагаю что мой пример поддержит 95% браузеров среднестатистического пользователя.